# Aggregate, Show Only Count >1 for each entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

### | Tag | Article Name | Article_ID  |

### |book| Florences      |  15

### |story| Florences      | 15

### |book| Jasmine        | 22

### |story| Florences      |  15

### |bells| Florences      | 15

### |story| Jasmine        | 22

I would like to display only when multiple of the same tags occur for the same article i.e. the results of the query on this table would show `book`,`Florences`, `count(2)` and `story`,`Jasmine`,`count(2)`. I have tried using the statement below but to no avail:

`SELECT Tag, Article_Name, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM articletagview
GROUP BY Article_Name
ORDER BY count DESC`

Comment: I don't see why the row `book,Florences` should show a count of 2, and neither `story,Jasmine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you'll want to use the "HAVING" clause (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), since you're using an aggregate function. So, something like:

```
SELECT Article_Name, Tag, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM articletagview
GROUP BY Article_Name, Tag
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

When using an aggregate function (like count), you'll want to either group by all the items in your select, or not include them in the select, otherwise you'll see some strange results.

Comment: You can refer to `count` alias in `HAVING` clause since `HAVING` occurs after `GROUP BY`. Also, I'm thinking you need to group by both article name and tag.

Comment: Re-reading the question, you'll want to group by both tag and article name. Edited answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT Tag, Article_Name, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM articletagview
GROUP BY Tag, Article_Name
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: I'm thinking this needs a `HAVING` clause somewhere and check your `GROUP BY` order.